# Python: Concatenating Strings from Grouped analysis

Tags: python, pandas

I need some help concatenating some strings from a DF.

I have the below "original" df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Material': [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3],
                'BOM': ['A','B',np.nan,'A',np.nan,'C','A','A','B','C']})
```

|  | Material | BOM |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 1 | B |
| 2 | 1 | NaN |
| 3 | 2 | A |
| 4 | 2 | NaN |
| 5 | 2 | C |
| 6 | 3 | A |
| 7 | 3 | A |
| 8 | 3 | B |
| 9 | 3 | C |

Expected Result is:

| Material | BOM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A, B |
| 2 | A, C |
| 3 | A, B, C |

I'm new with Python and am thinking of doing it with a mix of Loop and Dict but definitely think there must be a better way.

The tricky bit is that I think I need to group by material and check column "BOM" for the distinct options (different than NaN) then some sort of ", ".join them.

I've tried the following:

```
df.groupby('Material')['BOM'].apply(', '.join)
```

And got the error:

```
"TypeError: sequence item 2: expected str instance, float found".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `dropna` and `drop_duplicates`, then `GroupBy.agg`:

```
df.dropna().drop_duplicates().groupby('Material').agg(', '.join)
```

or:

```
df.dropna().groupby('Material').agg(lambda s: ', '.join(s.drop_duplicates()))
```

output:

```
              BOM
Material         
1            A, B
2            A, C
3         A, B, C
```

Answer (score 1):

3 solutions depending on output requirements:

Using `.agg`:
`df.dropna().drop_duplicates().groupby('Material').agg(', '.join)`

Output:

```
              BOM
Material         
1            A, B
2            A, C
3         A, B, C
```

Using `.apply(list)`:
`df.dropna().drop_duplicates().groupby('Material')['BOM'].apply(list).reset_index()`

Output:

```
   Material        BOM
0         1     [A, B]
1         2     [A, C]
2         3  [A, B, C]
```

Using `.apply(set)`: `df.dropna().groupby('Material')['BOM'].apply(set).reset_index()`

Output:

```
   Material        BOM
0         1     {A, B}
1         2     {A, C}
2         3  {A, C, B}
```